# ¿Cómo detectar la orientacion(horizontal o vertical) en android de la pantalla en la clase java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

hola quisiera saber como puedo obtener la orientación de la pantalla en la clase java de una actividad en android. Seria algo como

```
if(pantalla portrait){
...hago esto...
}else{
...hago esto otro...
}
```

Comment: Deberías poner lo que has intentado hasta ahora. Lo que preguntas se encuentra muy fácilmente en Google así pues especifica tu problema y danos [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Cerrar? En serio? Con un pregunta clara y tres buenas respuestas? **cabezamesa**

Comment: @Awes0meM4n y qué pasa si se encuentra "facilmente" en Google?

Answer (score 9):

Debes tomar en cuenta que algunos dispositivos pueden tener diferentes orientaciones, considero esto es más adecuado:

```
public String getRotation(Context context){
    final int rotation = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();
           switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                return "vertical";
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                return "horizontal";
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                return "vertical inversa";
            default:
                return "horizontal inversa";
            }
        }
```

Esto para definir si la orientación es horizontal o vertical aún siendo esta inversa.

---

Si solo deseas saber si es horizontal o vertical entonces serìa como lo comentas Felix :

```
public String getRotation(Context context){
    final int rotation = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();
           switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                return "vertical";
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:                           
            default:
                return "horizontal";
            }
        }
```

---

Para llamar el método se realizaría de esta forma:

```
if(getRotation(getApplicationContext()).equals("vertical")){ //es vertical o portrait.
...hago esto...
}else{ // es horizontal o landscape.
...hago esto otro...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Lo que preguntas es bastante sencillo. La siguiente linea de código:

```
Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

devuelve dos valores:

```
ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT y ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
```

Con eso ya puedes hacer lo que pides.
Espero que te haya ayudado.

Saludos.

Comment: gracias man, ya resolvi con la respeusta que publique @Curro

Comment: Podrías agregar de donde vienen los constantes que usas (Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE...) para merecerte el voto aun más ;)

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta @Stefan. Esas constantes son constantes del sistema Android.

Comment: No hay constantes de un sistema en Java, solamente hay constantes de clases, y si usas una constante en Java tienes que dar la clase o importar la clase para usarlo. Tu respuesta es mucho más útil si incluyes con las constantes la clase que los define.

Answer (score 4):

hola ya encontre mi propia respuesta

```
int rotacion = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        if (rotacion == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotacion == Surface.ROTATION_180) {
           //...hacer lo que quiera con la pantalla vertical
        } else {
            //...hacer lo que quiera con la pantalla horizontal
        }
```